# the line height in between <p> tags is different

Tags: html, css, height, line

I am trying to make a simple home page and I am getting slightly different line heights between

tags. Here is the HTML `

Justin is the lead engineer for

```
        <p>and also this &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp and Justin also  </p> 
            <a href="http://brabble.com"><img id="brabble" src="img/brabble.png"></a>

        <p>to make products work </p>`
```

and here is a picture [image: line height issues]

Comment: If I had to guess, It's probably related to your image.

Comment: It's likely that the image is larger than the text, increase the text size or shrink the image.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I have a 0px margin and a 0px padding on the image. Would this not make a difference?

Comment: What are the dimensions on the image?

Comment: @ZackAronson because margin and padding aside, the image still probably has a height more than that of your text.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 the dimensions are 20x20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is getting in the way of text formatting because it's not the same size as your text. You have several options, the most effective will be to put the image in its own span, and give that span an explicit height of 1em, with an overflow:visible:

```
<P>lalalala <span class='imagewrapper'><img ....></span> more text</p>
```

with style:

```
.imagewrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/UG5us/

Answer (score 0):

The image causes a line box to become taller than specified by the line height of the surrounding element. To avoid this, scale the image down and/or set its vertical position.